# What version of XCode will support iOS 3.0?

Tags: iphone

I want my app to support the largest audience possible. I am thinking this would be iOS 3.0 to iOS 7.0. I originally wrote the app using XCode 5.0 but because I used storyboarding I could only support users that had iOS 5.0 or higher at the time. At this point, I am thinking of reworking the app so it no longer uses storyboarding and using a lower version of XCode. I am also wondering how to support iOS 7.0 as while supporting iOS 3.0 users?

Was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Going by these numbers https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_7/from_date%3a-56,to_date:0 I would just go for iOS5 and higher.

Comment: Thanks. I used auto-sizing to deal with the different form factors but it requires iOS 6.0. What is alternative way to handle this? Thanks!

Comment: The alternative is to use two storyboards or [multiple targets](http://hariniachala.blogspot.hu/2012/01/creating-multiple-targets-in-ios.html). Check also [layoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews). However, if it's a new app, I would recommend just going with iOS 7 since more and more people upgrade to iOS 7. Many APIs are exclusive, but very helpful for your development, such as AutoLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single version of Xcode that will support both iOS 3.0 and 4" iOS 7 devices.

Only Xcode versions 4.4 and earlier can generate armv6 code for iOS 3 devices.  Later ones cannot.

And Apple no longer allows submitting iPhone apps without 4" display support, which requires Xcode 4.5 or later, and building with the iOS 6 SDK or later.  The lowest iOS version which Xcode 5 and the iOS SDK 7 supports is iOS 4.3.

Some iOS developers have reported success using the OS X lipo command-line tool to combine binary slices from both Xcode 4.4 and Xcode 5, but this usage is unsupported.